# SFML.NET particle system

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, particles, sfml

I've written particle systems before and, put simply, it's more effort than it's worth given the size of the projects I want it for. What I'm ideally looking for is a particle system which can be easily dropped into an SFML.NET project without needing a great deal of manual integration.

Does anything already exist to fill this need (ideally without needing to rely on Tao for OpenGL access), or can someone recommend a particle system they've used for another .NET-based grapics framework which should be fairly easy to adapt?

Keep in mind that if it needs work to integrate wtih SFML.NET, the work involved should be LESS than the work required to write one from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flint Particles (Formerly flint-sharp):
http://flintparticles.org/

Comment: They've changed names and moved off google code. Link updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about [SPARK](http://spark.developpez.com/index.php?page=features&lang=en) (also [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=829&sid=e14f3810bd0ddc658753686c3b698bcf))? It's written in C++, but it claims to integrate with SFML, and it may well be that porting the C++ to .NET would be less work than writing a particle system from scratch.

Comment: I've already looked at SPARK but, having had a surprising number of complications porting even a simple network library from C++ to .NET in the past, I have no desire to repeat the effort :) Any solution needs to already be .NET-based.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the simple but unfortunate answer is: no.